# Executing a shell script with code accepted using I/O indirection

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to execute a script like this, accepting script using indirection

```
sh <<EOT
for str in `cat test`
do
 echo $str
done
EOT
```

The file "test" has contents

```
a
b
c
```

It gives below error.

```
sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `b'
sh: line 2: `b'
```

Can anyone clarify ?.  My aim is to execute the script like above instead of creating a shell script file script.sh and executing it (which works fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer shell is interpolating the HEREDOC.   To prevent that, quote the delimiter:

```
sh << 'EOT'
```

To clarify, what you have is equivalent to:

```
sh <<EOT
for str in a
b
c
do
 echo
done
EOT
```

which makes the syntax error fairly obvious.